# Dynamically created elements don't trigger events despite using .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**NOTE that I'm already using .on function as most of the answers suggest. This problem is vastly different than other problems of the same category.**

My HTML Code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Order Stack</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div>
            <h1>Enter Your Order</h1>
            <div id="orderBox">
                <input type="textbox" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="textbox" id="order" placeholder="Order">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Order Now">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="orderList">
            <h1>Pending Order List</h1>
            <p class="orderDisp">
                <span class="orderId">OrderID:</span> 1 <span class="orderName">Name:</span> John Doe <span class="orderContent">Order:</span> CheeseBurger
                <img class="deleteBtn" src="images/delete.png" alt="Delete Order">
            </p>
            <p class="orderDisp">
                <span class="orderId">OrderID:</span> 2 <span class="orderName">Name:</span> Jane Doe <span class="orderContent">Order:</span> Steak
                <img class="deleteBtn" src="images/delete.png" alt="Delete Order">
            </p>
            <p class="orderDisp">
                <span class="orderId">OrderID:</span> 3 <span class="orderName">Name:</span> Santa Claus <span class="orderContent">Order:</span> Chicken Zinger Burger
                <img class="deleteBtn" src="images/delete.png" alt="Delete Order">
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS is :

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    background: #F2E5A0 url(images/The-Cheeseburger.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 50px;
}

h1 {
    color: #000;
}

#orderBox {
    background-color: #B7BBDC;
    padding: 25px;
}

#name {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

#order {
    width: 500px;
}

#container {
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: #F2C095;
    padding: 50px;
    min-width: 875px;
}

.orderDisp {
    background-color: #A6D98F;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.orderId, .orderName, .orderContent {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #223A2B;
}

.deleteBtn {
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;

    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 95%;
}
```

My jQuery is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var orderId=4; // Starting form 4

    $("#submit").click(function() {

        var orderName = $("#name").val();
        var orderContent = $("#order").val();
        orderName = orderName.trim();
        orderContent = orderContent.trim();

        if((orderName !== "") && (orderContent !== ""))
        {
            $p = $('<p class="orderDisp">');

            var content = '<span class="orderId">OrderID:</span> '+orderId+' <span class="orderName">Name:</span> '+orderName+' <span class="orderContent">Order:</span> '+orderContent;
            content += '<img class="deleteBtn" src="images/delete.png" alt="Delete Order">';

            $p.append(content);
            $p.appendTo('#orderList');
        }

        $("#name").val("");
        $("#order").val("");
    });

    $("#order").keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
            $("#submit").click();
    });

    $(".deleteBtn").on('click',function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

});
```

To describe the problem, [here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Somu2016/9bjszpxa/).

I know that dynamically created elements (elements created via code) are not triggered normally by `.click()` event handlers. One has to use `.on("event", function() { ...code...});` to bind the event to the element. I've already done this. Yet, somehow, the deleteBtn's code is still not triggered. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: `$('#orderList').on('click', '.deleteBtn', function() {`

Comment: @Tushar Would `$(".deleteBtn").on('click', function() {...code...}` not work? Coz I tried it, and it's not working. Any ideas why, Sir?

Comment: @SomenathSinha you need to attach the `.on()` event handler on an ancestor element, not the selector itself, therefore what Tushar said will work but `$(".deleteBtn").on('click', function() {...code...}` won't, as you can see [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: @DarkAjax But by using Tushar's code, what we're effectively doing is selecting only those elements within `orderList` that have a class of `.deleteBtn`. How is that any different from directly selecting `.deleteBtn` elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstood the difference between `on('click', ...)` and `click(..)`

The whole point is that `.deleteBtn` doesn't yet exist when you bind the event, so it doesn't make any difference if you use try to bind an event to `.deleteBtn` using `on` or `click`, **because it does not exist**.

But `#orderList` is already on the page, so you can bind an event listener to it. You could do it like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // this code runs once on document.ready - .deleteBtn doesn't exist
  $('#orderList').click(function(event){
    // this code runs every time #orderList receives a click - .deleteBtn may exist at this point
    if( $(event.target).closest('.deleteBtn').length > 0 ) { 
      // click happened on .deleteBtn or one of its children
    }
  })
})
```

This way, you capture clicks that happen on `#orderList`, then check the `event.target` for the exact element inside of `#orderList` that bubbled up the event. The `on` method binds the event, and provides an argument to do that check for you, so you would rewrite the above as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#orderList').on('click', '.deleteBtn', function(event){
      // click happened on .deleteBtn or one of its children
  })
})
```

I have updated your fiddle to demonstrate that - https://jsfiddle.net/9bjszpxa/3/